# Reading next line in Java

Tags: java, io

There seem to be multiple ways of doing I/O in Java. How does one decide which one to use.
For example:

I can accept user's input through stdin in the following two ways:

Method 1:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = "";
    try{
        System.out.println("Enter: ");
        input = br.readLine();

    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Method 2:

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Scanner: ");
        input = sc.nextLine();      
        System.out.println(input);
```

I'm pretty sure there might be other ways to read the input as well. Are there any guidelines which i can follow when selecting which method to use for a particular kind of operation(Reading from files,sockets,stdin)

Comment: KISS - Keep it simple as possible.

Comment: @BalusC You forgot that last S on that :P

Comment: For finding the simplest way, i need to know all the ways :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guideline is that you use a class that has the API you need. If you are just reading lines, `BufferedReader.readLine()`. If you are reading tokens and want them converted for you, `Scanner`. If you are reading binary data, `DataInputStream`. If you are reading objects, `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`. If you're reading XML, an XML parser. Etc etc etc. If you're reading Java, `JavaCC` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The method in which you read input from any source in Java is directly related to the Data in which you plan to be reading from that source. If you want to read plain text/primitive types then `Scanner` is nice and simple, but you can go so far as to use an `ObjectInputStream` if you plan on reading whole Objects from the source.

If you want a source, [Java I/O Streams](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/ProgIOStreams/).